# Odd (?) spacing for mapping notation

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I recently wrote up an answer on MSE that involved the mapping `f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}`; the output looked a little different to me, and thus I thought it could have something to do with MathJax, but the same thing happens when I produce the mapping with regular LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item$f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$
    \item$f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\;\mathbb{R^+}$
    \item$f\colon\mathbb{R^+}\!\!\to\mathbb{R^+}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

In my opinion, (1) looks a little weird in terms of spacing (the arrow seems to be too far right of the first `R^+`), but what about (2) and (3)? To my eye, (2) looks best, but perhaps there is a little too much space, and (3) looks too condensed.

Maybe it is just my very untrained eye for typography coming into play--does (1) look a little "weird" or "off" to any of you or am I off-base? Also, is there anything particularly good or bad about (2) or (3)?

Comment: TeX adds `\scriptspace` after a sub/superscript, the default is 0.5pt (a bit less than 0.2mm). There is also the optical “hole” created by the shape of +, which is probably responsible for the seeming big space. If you really feel it's too wide, you can try with `\!\to`. But  the third example has too big backspacing. The second one is just wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg After trying it with just one `\!`, it does look a little bit better than (3) I suppose. I was just very surprised by the big space--maybe it's really not worth worrying about, seeing as I imagine many people use it all the time without any issues.

Comment: As I said, the shapes of symbols can create optical illusions or real clashes; for instance, one should type `\sqrt{\,\log 3}` because of the tall letter (clash) or `x^2\!/2` to compensate for the hole created by the relative shapes (optical). Such details make a difference when good typography is concerned.

Comment: You might try this: `f\colon\mathbb R^+\mkern-1.5mu\to\mathbb{R^+}`

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I tried fooling around with that, and I think most of what it comes down to is simply me needing a better eye (something that comes with experience I know). For example, I thought using `-2.5mu` looked pretty good, but I can't tell too much of a difference from that and simply `\!`.

Comment: `\! = –3mu`. Often a good soluton with such problems is to use ½ or ¼ of `!` or `\,`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a comparison where I used `alignat` for having the arrows vertical aligned (in the first two rows); the third row applies a negative kern.

[image]

In the right column I show that the spacing is actually exactly the same in both cases, using a hairline.

The difference is an optical illusion created by the shape of the symbols: the + has a “hole” that seems to leave a bigger space than what's actually used.

In such cases, a `\!` is usually the simplest and most effective method.

Here's the code for producing the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
R^+&\to &\qquad R^{+\smash{\vrule width 0.1pt height 1ex depth 5ex}}&\to \\
R^2&\to &\qquad R^2&\to \\
R^+&\!\to
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

If we add also a symbol after the arrow, we see that the `\!` does its service well:

[image]

This was obtained with `R^+\!\to R^+`. The situation is similar to input such as `x^2/2`, where a `\!` gives a better result: compare

```
\[
x^2/2 \qquad x^2\!/2
\]
```

[image]

Curing such details greatly improves the typographic quality of a document.

Comment: That's awesome. What you were saying before made a fair amount of sense, but I really appreciate you going more in depth and providing nice illustrations. Thanks!